# Query containing multiple joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have the following three tables/models in a Rails application:

```
class ProgramType < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :position

  has_many :programs
end

class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :site_id, :start_date, :end_date, :program_type_id,
                  :active, :name,:short_name

  belongs_to :program_type
  has_many :sessions
end

class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :program
end
```

The following query returns all of the records in the `sessions` table, instead of returning just those of the specified `ProgramType`. What am I doing wrong?

```
Session
  .active
  .joins(:program)
  .joins(:program => :program_type)
  .where('program_types.name = ?', "Summer Domestic")
```

I trying to retrieve only those Session records belonging to a Programs of a specific ProgramType.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is your `active` scope ?

Comment: The active scope selects on an active boolean. I get the same result without it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have a problem related to the fact that AR does not know you're actually using `program_types`, because you use a SQL string. Try this :

```
Session
 .active
 .joins( program: :program_type )
 .where( program_types: {name: "Summer Domestic"} )
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I found the -- very dumb -- problem. There is nothing wrong with the query.

Comment: feel free to delete your own question or to answer it yourself for posterity, then.